# Getting top 20 scores in Parse

Tags: parse-platform, unity-game-engine

I have an endless runner game in Unity3D with a leaderboard set up in Parse. Every time the user starts the game up, I query the leaderboard for the top 20 scores, like this:

```
var scoresQuery = ParseObject.GetQuery ("Users").OrderByDescending("HighScore").WhereGreaterThan("HighScore", 100).Limit(20);
var scoresQueryTask = scoresQuery.FindAsync ();
```

This works fine, but how would it perform with a 100,000 or a million (if only!) rows?

Is there a better way to get these top scores?

Comment: It will be fast. as long as you don't try to return zillions of rows, top 20 or 100, or 1k max will be fast.

Comment: Oh good, I was worried if running a sort across a million rows would be expensive or take too long.